# Drupal 7 upgrade user_external_login no longer exists, what is a new solution?

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am upgrading a CMS that used

```
$logged_in = user_external_login($account);
```

to verify a login after they hit an external service.

http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7 suggested this solution

```
   user_login_submit(array(), array('uid' => $account->uid));
   drupal_goto();
```

This throws a "Only variables can be passed by reference" error at runtime. I am unsure what else to do. Looking around like here http://drupal.org/node/497612 the same solution is suggested. Can someone please fill me in on what I am missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this line:

```
 user_login_submit(array(), array('uid' => $account->uid));
```

... it expects the second parameter to be a reference.  What you gave it was a value, which is  not a reference.

Try this instead:

```
$account = array('uid' => $account->uid);
user_login_submit(array(), $account);
// rest of your code follows after...
```

I think the documentation is messed up on Drupal.org.  `user_login_submit(array(), array('uid' => $account->uid));` is not correct, unless I missed something.